# how to display json value in radio group

Tags: json, angular, ionic4, radio-group

l want to load local data json in radio group option , this local data json content information of cities .

json

```
{
    "stations": {
        "station": [
            {
                "_name": "Khasab Port",
                "_ar_name": "ميناء خصب",
                "_cccc": "OOKP",
                "_city_forecast_name": "Khasab_Port",
                "_metar_avail": "true",
                "_iii": "41240",
                "_lat": "26.2105",
                "_lon": "56.244",
                "_elev": "4.0",
            },          {
            "_name": "Khasab Airport",
            "_ar_name": "مطار خصب",
            "_cccc": "OOKB",
            "_city_forecast_name": "Khassab_Airport",
            "_metar_avail": "true",
            "_iii": "41241",
            "_lat": "26.161722",
            "_lon": "56.23672",
            "_elev": "29.0",
            "_image": "KhasabAirport.jpg"
        },
        {
            "_name": "Diba",
            "_ar_name": "دبا",
            "_cccc": "OODB",
            "_city_forecast_name": "Dibba",
            "_metar_avail": "true",
            "_iii": "41242",
            "_lat": "25.615627",
            "_lon": "56.247322",
            "_elev": "10.0",
            "_image": "Diba.jpg"
        },

        ]
    }
}
```

how can l load this json list in radio group ?

example like that

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>{{_name}}</ion-label>
  <ion-radio slot="start" value="{{_lat}},{{_lon}}"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

any idea please with code ? l am using ionic4 and angualr

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is the *ion-radio-group* and a **ngFor* loop.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-radio-group>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let station of stations" >
      <ion-label>{{ station._name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio slot="start" [value]="station._lat + ',' + station._lon"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

Where *stations* is a property of your component class where you load the json values from a Service.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: 'component.html',
    styleUrls: ['component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public stations;

    constructor(
        private _assetsService : AssetsService 
    ) { }

   ngOnInit(){
       this._assetsService.getStations().subscribe(
          data => this.stations = data.stations.station
       );
   }

}
```

And you can load the JSON data by reading your local file through HttpClient.

```
@Injectable()
export class AssetsService {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public getStations(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("./assets/stations.json")
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer . l got error `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays`.

Comment: My mistake, just realized your array has a property "station" inside "stations".
So it was trying to loop "stations", which is an object, and not "stations.station", which is an array. I fixed my answer.

Comment: same problem [object Object]

Comment: l am using httplclint l am not using the first code . and why l cant make in http clinet like that `this.stations = data.stations.station` ? l get error he accept only `this.stations = data.`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are doing, could you show some of your code?
Http Client get returns an Observable and that's why you can't acess the data directly, you have to subscribe its content.

Comment: l did like that : `this.https.get('./assets/ali.json').subscribe((data) => {
    
        this.station = data
        console.log(this.station)
      })` l dont know how to use `returns an Observable`